# Dash rc files for non-login non-interactive shells

Tags: shell, bashrc, sh

Does dash have a non-interactive non-login rc file? I've read the man page, which recommends `.profile` for login shells and `$ENV` environment variable for interactive shells.

Is there anything that runs for non-interactive non-login shells, such as `zsh`'s `zshenv` files, or `bash`'s `$BASH_ENV` environment variable? Is there an equivalent file for Bourne shell too?

---

Best I can come up with so far (although not ideal at all as it requires me editing every single script) is to edit the shebang as follows:

```
#!/bin/sh /path/to/script

f
```

where `/path/to/script` contains

```
f() { echo "/path/to/script"; }
```